# How to left-align ticks in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I need to left align the month ticks.  And I can't use a hard-coded value to shift them because the number of weeks per month is not constant.

There's so many questions like this here but none have working answers.  Seems like this is such a common problem maybe there's an in-built function out there I'm not aware of that can handle this for me.

Also notice there are a variable number of weeks per month, yet the spacing of the months is constant.  How can I fix that?

EDIT: `let x2 = d3.scalePoint().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0)` left aligns the entire set of month ticks.  But this means only the first tick is properly positioned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width='960' height='500'></svg>
<style>
  .bar {
    fill: steelblue
  }

  .bar:hover {
    fill: brown
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: MidnightBlue;
    stroke-width: .5px;
  }
</style>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js'></script>
<script>
  `use strict`;
  (async o => {
    let svg = d3.select(`svg`)
    let margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 }
    let width = +svg.attr(`width`) - margin.left - margin.right
    let height = +svg.attr(`height`) - margin.top - margin.bottom
    height -= 100
    let g = svg.append(`g`).attr(`transform`, `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

    let x = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .padding(0.1)

    let x2 = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .padding(0.1)

    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0])

    let data = [{"week":"July_1_2019","profit":"100"},{"week":"July_8_2019","profit":"394"},{"week":"August_3_2019","profit":"395"},{"week":"August_14_2019","profit":"112"},{"week":"August_24_2019","profit":"488"},{"week":"September_7_2019","profit":"123"},{"week":"September_14_2019","profit":"534"},{"week":"September_21_2019","profit":"600"},{"week":"September_22_2019","profit":"604"},{"week":"September_23_2019","profit":"788"},{"week":"October_10_2019","profit":"433"},{"week":"October_11_2019","profit":"100"}]

    function formatWeek(week) {
      let datum = week.split(`_`)
      return { month: datum[0], day: +datum[1], year: +datum[2] }
    }

    x.domain(data.map(o => o.week))
    x2.domain(data.map(o => formatWeek(o.week).month))
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, o => Number(o.profit))])

    g.append(`g`)
      .attr(`transform`, `translate(0,${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(o => `${formatWeek(o).month} ${formatWeek(o).day}, ${formatWeek(o).year}`))
      .selectAll(`text`)
      .style(`text-anchor`, `end`)
      .attr(`dx`, `-1em`)
      .attr(`dy`, `-0.5em`)
      .attr(`transform`, d => `rotate(-90)`)

    g.append(`g`)
      .call(d3.axisTop(x2))
      .selectAll(`text`)
      .style(`text-anchor`, `end`)

    g.append(`g`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append(`text`)
      .attr(`fill`, `#000`)
      .attr(`transform`, `rotate(-90)`)
      .attr(`y`, 6)
      .attr(`dy`, `0.71em`)
      .attr(`text-anchor`, `end`)
      .text(`profit`)

    g.selectAll(`.bar`)
      .data(data)
      .enter().append(`rect`)
      .attr(`class`, `bar`)
      .attr(`x`, o => x(o.week))
      .attr(`y`, o => y(Number(o.profit)))
      .attr(`width`, x.bandwidth())
      .attr(`height`, o => height - y(Number(o.profit)))

    function make_y_gridlines() { return d3.axisTop(x2) }

    g.append(`g`)
      .attr(`class`, `line`)
      .call(make_y_gridlines().tickSize(-width).tickFormat(``))

  })()
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean by 'ticks'. The blue graph bars, the separator lines between months, or the top labels of months ('July', 'August', ...) ? Please supply a static picture with a desired alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust the ticks based on the x position of the first bar in each month. Without changing your code too much, under `x.domain(data.map(o => o.week))` add:

```
// get month names and first bar in month
let monthNames = d3.set(data.map(o => formatWeek(o.week).month)).values(),
    monthVals = monthNames.map(function(d) {  return data.filter(function(e) {  return e.week.match(d) != null })[0].week});

x2.domain(monthVals)
```

Then change your calls to your top axis and gridlines to :

```
g.append(`g`)
  .call(d3.axisTop(x2).tickValues(monthNames))
  .call(function(context) {
        // bind the first months to the ticks and adjust
        var ticks = context.selectAll('.tick')
        .data(monthVals)
        .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + x(d) + ',0)' })

   })
  .selectAll(`text`)
  .style(`text-anchor`, `end`)
```

And:

```
g.append(`g`)
  .attr(`class`, `line`)
  .call(make_y_gridlines().tickSize(-width).tickFormat(``))
  .call(function(context) {
      // bind the first months to the lines and adjust
       context.selectAll('.tick')
        .data(monthVals)
        .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + x(d) + ',0)' })
  })
```